# JNI: calling C from java

Tags: c, java-native-interface

I am writing a C implementation for Java Code and it is a simple HelloWorld code.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
}
```

But I would like to call another function in this function called callmethod:

```
int callmethod(JNIENV *env, jint a, jint b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

Is there any way to call `int callmethod(JNIENV *env, jint a, jint b)` which is not declared java code to be called in the method `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your native method written in C can do anything any other C program can do, including calling other functions:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) {
   jint a=3, b=4;
   printf("sum=%d\n", callmethod(env, a, b));
   return;
}
```

Comment: @npatel That's a warning, not an error. You should provide a declaration for `callmethod()`.